# React-Konva: Prevent draggable image reverting position after placing point

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konvajs

Using React-Konva, I've created a zoomable canvas/stage that contains a draggable image. Points can also be plotted on a layer in the canvas.

The aim is to be able to drag the image (and zoom onto the stage) and then plot points at specific points over the image. The problem is, if I drag the image, then plot a point, the image will snap back to it's pre-drag position. I want the image to stay in the position I dragged it to.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

A demo of my code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/8lm5p56y6l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `render()` function you have this code:

```
<Image
  draggable
  x={0}
  y={0}
  image={this.state.image}
  ref={node => {
    this.imageNode = node;
  }}
  rotation={this.state.angle}
/>
```

`react-konva` always update props of shape exactly how you described them in `render` function. So it will update the position of the image back to `{0,0}` as soon as you update the component.

To prevent it you may skip `x` and `y` and do not define them (as they are just zeros).

Or you can save the position of the image on `dragend` into state of the component:

```
handleImageDragEnd = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    imageX: e.target.x(),
    imageY: e.target.y(),
  });
}

// later in render:

<Image
  draggable
  x={this.state.imageX}
  y={this.state.imageY}
  image={this.state.image}
  ref={node => {
    this.imageNode = node;
  }}
  rotation={this.state.angle}
  onDragEnd={this.handleImageDragEnd}
/>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/2olo66jmqr

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that would be something as simple as that. P.S. huge fan of your work with Konva!